# Creating Graphviz edges with for loop

Tags: python, graphviz

Take a family tree for example:

```
grandparents = ['Frank', 'Kelly']
parent = ['John']
kids = ['Emily', 'Mary', 'Sue']
```

I understand that I could do:

```
dot.node('F', 'Frank')
dot.node('K', 'Kelly')
dot.node('J', 'John')
dot.node('E', 'Emily')
...
dot.edges(['FJ','KJ','JE',...])
```

And the intended structure of the output should be fairly obvious:

```
F -> J
K -> J
J -> E
J -> M
J -> S
```

But I have too many elements that need to be included for me to do this manually and I can't figure out how to make this work in conjunction with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In semi pseudo-code it would look something like (I'm assuming you're using PyGraphviz or something similar.

```
for grandparent g

    Graph.add_node(g.id, g.name)

    for parent p

        Graph.add_node(p.id, p.name)
        Graph.add_edge(g.id, p.id)

        for kid k

            Graph.add_node(k.id, k.name)
            Graph.add_edge(p.id, k.id)
```

And then do the same but using parent and kid. You'd need to define a unique identifier (e.g. F for Frank) for each name. For loops won't work well going back further in a family. For that you'd want to use a tree structure and recursion.